# every accordion opens when i click on any accordion : react js

Tags: reactjs

every accordion opens when I click on any accordions can anyone help with this I want only one to open at a time

```
const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
```

```
<div className="accordion">
  {Object.values(mapped).map((item, index) => (
    //{predefined.map(({ date }) => (
      <div className="accordion-item">
        <div
          className="accordion-title"
          onClick={() => setIsActive(!isActive)}
        >
          <div>{item[0].date}</div> <div>11:45</div> 
          <div>painscale</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>{isActive ? "-" : "+"}</div>
        </div>
        {isActive && (
              <div className="accordion-content">
                <table>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                    
                      <th>sdcs</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  {item.map((e) => {
                    return (
                      <tr>
                        <td> {e.time}</td> <td>{e.d}</td>{" "}
                        <td> {e.scale}</td> <td>{escale.}</td>
                      </tr>
                    );
                  })}
                </table>
              </div>
            )}
      </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

every accordion opens when I click on any accordions can anyone help with this I want only one to open at a time

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `isActive` state is a general one to the component and therefore would control all other elements in that component together.

However, to achieve what you're looking for, you can change that to an active current Index like so:

```
const [activeCurrentIndex, setActiveCurrentIndex] = useState();

const toggleShowAccordion = (id) => {
    if(activeCurrentIndex === id){
        setActiveCurrentIndex();
    } else {
        setActiveCurrentIndex(id);
    }
}

//....

<div className="accordion">
  {predefined.map(({ id, date, time , pain_scale, time_stamp})) => (
    <div className="accordion-item" key={id}>
      <div className="accordion-title" onClick={() => toggleShowAccordion(id)}>
        <div>{date}</div>
        <div>{isActive ? "-" : "+"}</div>
      </div>
      {activeCurrentIndex === id && <div className="accordion-content">{time} {pain_scale} {time_stamp}</div>}
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

You're setting the `activeCurrentIndex` to that of the accordion you want to expand and you check if the activeCurrentIndex state is same as accordion's id to expand the menu otherwise, it's closed. You also need to supply a key to each element while mapping through an array

Comment: this works but i doesnot close if there is only one accordant

Comment: Yeah, I already edited my answer. Missed that use case